# apt is (unsuccessfully) looking for Components-amd64.yml on arm64 repo set up with apt-mirror

Tags: apt, 18.04, apt-mirror, debootstrap, arm64

Repro:

Install CentOS 7 server, then deploy Ubuntu 18.04 environment via debootstrap:

```
yum install epel-release
yum install debootsrap
mkdir /opt/ubuntu-18.04
ln -s /opt/ubuntu-18.04 /opt/ubuntu
debootstrap --arch=amd64 bionic /opt/ubuntu http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

Enter chroot:

```
chroot /opt/ubuntu
```

Install apt-mirror:

```
apt install software-properties-common
add-apt-repository universe
apt install apt-mirror
```

Set up `/etc/apt/mirror.list` for multiple architectures. `bionic-updates` and `bionic-backports`, and also `restricted`, `universe` and `multiverse` are left out to speed up testing:

```
set nthreads     20
set _tilde 0

deb-i386  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main
# restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main
# restricted universe multiverse
deb-arm64 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic main
# restricted universe multiverse

#deb-i386  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-arm64 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse

#deb-i386  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-arm64 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

clean http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
clean http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
```

Perform the sync:

```
sudo -u apt-mirror apt-mirror
```

Set up your HTTP server of choice (I use nginx), the directory structure looks like this:

```
# ls -al /var/www/html
total 62100
drwxr-xr-x. 3 nginx nginx     4096 Jul  2 13:54 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 nginx nginx     4096 Jul  1 20:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root  root      4096 Jul  1 17:42 seed
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root  root        65 Jul  1 20:10 ubuntu -> /opt/ubuntu/var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
-rw-r--r--. 1 root  root  63564717 Jul  1 17:43 ubuntu-18.04-netinstall.zip
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root  root        69 Jul  2 13:54 ubuntu-ports -> /opt/ubuntu/var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
```

Set up `/etc/apt/sources.list` on your Ubuntu 18.04 desktop client. Same things are left out, but they behave the same way, with `-updates` and `-backports` it'll cause 3 files missing and returning 404:

```
# Security

deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse

# Internal mirror

deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://apt.foobar.com/ubuntu bionic main
# restricted universe multiverse
#deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://apt.foobar.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
#deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://apt.foobar.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb [arch=arm64] https://apt.foobar.com/ubuntu-ports bionic main
# restricted universe multiverse
#deb [arch=arm64] https://apt.foobar.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
#deb [arch=arm64] https://apt.foobar.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

# Canonical fallback mirror

deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Now perform `apt update` (same result with `apt-get update`):

```
# apt update
Get:1 https://apt.foobar.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]
Get:2 https://apt.foobar.com/ubuntu-ports bionic InRelease [242 kB]                                                                      
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                    
Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com bionic-security InRelease                                                                    
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88,7 kB]                                                  
Hit:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com bionic InRelease                                                                                        
Hit:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com bionic-updates InRelease                                                                                
Hit:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com bionic-backports InRelease                                                  
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74,6 kB]
Get:10 https://apt.foobar.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main arm64 Packages [975 kB]    
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]         
Get:12 https://apt.foobar.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main Translation-en [516 kB]           
Get:13 https://apt.foobar.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [477 kB]    
Get:13 https://apt.foobar.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [477 kB]    
Ign:13 https://apt.foobar.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                       
Ign:13 https://apt.foobar.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                   
Ign:13 https://apt.foobar.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata             
Err:13 https://apt.foobar.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata             
  404  Not Found [IP: 10.1.3.96 443]
Fetched 494 kB in 1s (659 kB/s)                                                              
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch https://apt.foobar.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  404  Not Found [IP: 10.1.3.96 443]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

There was a hint on #ubuntu that it's because the `ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic/Release` file lists `Components-amd64.yml`. Now, the problem with that is that it's listed in the official ports.ubuntu.com file too, and that folder structure doesn't have `Components-amd64.yml` either, yet, `apt update` only gives the 404 errors for the local mirror.

We've been using this local mirror just fine with amd64/i386 packages on a few clients already, it's only the arm64 repo files that give this error.

**What am I doing wrong? Why is apt looking for amd64 files on an arm64 repo?**

---

**Update:** after messing around with debmirror I got the **exact same** issue. At this point it became suspicious that it's something on the client side. After digging into `/etc/apt` I've found the following excerpt in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream`:

```
    # The YAML metadata files
    deb::DEP-11  {
        MetaKey "$(COMPONENT)/dep11/Components-$(NATIVE_ARCHITECTURE).yml";
        ShortDescription "Components-$(NATIVE_ARCHITECTURE)";
        Description "$(RELEASE)/$(COMPONENT) $(NATIVE_ARCHITECTURE) DEP-11 Metadata";

        KeepCompressed "true";
        KeepCompressedAs "gz";
    };
```

Try this:

```
sed -i 's/NATIVE_ARCHITECTURE/ARCHITECTURE/' /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream
```

And the `apt update` problems are gone. **Can anyone confirm it's indeed an Ubuntu bug and this is indeed the solution to it?**